# React.js : re-rendering a component using react-router.link

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using react-router's Link to dynamically render my page. I am passing a list of suspects to it and based on the naturalPersonId parameter it should read the list and populate the respective details on the page. My problem is in each link componentI'm using (Link to="NaturalPerson"....
but based on the id passed I need to render the component so that the correct details are passed, but once I click on one link the component is rendered, but after that I click another link the component is not re-rendered. Is there a way to re render the same component everytime a different link is pressed.

Component using link :

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'nav',

    render: function render() {
        var activeClass = 'left-nav-selected';
        var optionList = this.props.optionList;
        return (
            <section className='left-nav' id='left-nav'>
                <div className='left-nav-title'></div>
                <nav className='left-nav-links'>
                    <ul>
                        {this.props.suspects.map(function(result,i) {
                                var navClass = 'nav-section'+i;
                                var suspectName=result.identity.first_name +"  "+ result.identity.last_name;
                                var entityNumber = result.entity_number;
                                return (
                                    <li key={i} className='left-nav-link' id={navClass}>
                                        <Link 
                                            to="NaturalPerson" 
                                            params={{naturalPersonId:entityNumber}}
                                            activeClassName={activeClass}
                                        >{suspectName}</Link>
                                    </li>

                                );
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </section>
        );
    }
});
```

NaturalPerson.jsx :

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            readOnly: true
        };
    },

    submit: function () {
        this.setState({readOnly: false});
        console.log(this.props.firstName);
    },

    save: function () {
        this.transitionTo('/');
    },

    componentDidMount: function () {
        console.log("naturalperson mounted");
    },

    render: function render() {
        var entityNumber = this.props.params.naturalPersonId;
        var suspects = this.props.suspects;
        var populatedSuspect;
        for (var i = 0; i < suspects.length; i++) {
            if (suspects[i].entity_number === entityNumber) {
                populatedSuspect = suspects[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        console.log("########" + populatedSuspect.identity.first_name);

        return (
            <form action="/Output" method="POST">
                <div id="container_suspects">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
                    <button type="button" onClick={this.submit}>Edit Details</button>
                    <div id="suspects_personal_details">
                        <PD 
                            hidden="hidden" 
                            readOnly={this.state.readOnly}
                            populatedSuspect={populatedSuspect}
                        />
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <PNS hidden="hidden" readOnly={this.state.readOnly}/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <Email readOnly={this.state.readOnly}/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="suspects_address">
                        <A readOnly={this.state.readOnly}/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
});
```

My routes look like this :

```
var routes = module.exports = (

    <Route path='/suspects' handler={SPA}>
    <Route name='NaturalPersonList' path='NaturalPersonList' handler={NaturalPersonList} >
    <Route name='NaturalPerson' path='NaturalPerson/:naturalPersonId' handler={NaturalPerson} />
    <Route name='EditNaturalPerson' path='EditNaturalPerson' handler={EditNaturalPerson}>
    <Route name='PersonalDetails' handler={PersonalDetails} />
    <Route name='NaturalPersonAddress' handler={NPAddress} />
    <Route name='PhoneNumbers' handler={PhoneNumbers} />
    <Route name='Email' handler={Email} />
    </Route>
    </Route>
    </Route>    
);
```

I am using react-router 0.13.3

Comment: what version of React Router are you using? Can you show us your routes?

Comment: @QoP..I have edited my question to include the routes as well.

Comment: I tried changing the state of the component using ComponentWillReceiveProps, still the components are not re rendered